# How to give discord bot owner's permissions?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a discord.py bot, no problems, my code just works fine, but i wanted to know how to give bot owner's permissions, he should remove a role that gives all high permissions, (all the permissions that are in Server>Server settings>roles>role name) so he should remove his role, but he gives this error:

discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

```
@bot.command(name="godRemove")
async def godremover(ctx, persona, numerogod):
    channel = bot.get_channel(id=786285288469037197)
    numerogod=int(numerogod)
    if not numerogod>1:
        numerogod=1
    #hasadded=False
    #hasgod=False
    rolenumber=0
    try:
        guild=ctx.guild
        if ctx.author.name in canAddGod:
            for i in guild.members:
                if str(i)[:-5].lower().strip()==persona.lower().strip():
                    for role in i.roles:
                        #if str(role)=="God":
                            #hasgod=True
                        if representsint(str(role)):
                            rolename=str(int(str(role))-numerogod).strip().lower()
                            rolenumber=int(rolename)
                            if rolenumber>1:
                                if discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=rolename)!=None:
                                    togiverole=discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=rolename)
                                    await i.add_roles(togiverole)
                                    await i.remove_roles(role)
                                    #hasadded=True
                                    await channel.send(removedliteral)
                                    return
                                else:
                                    togiverole=await ctx.guild.create_role(name=str(int(str(role))+numerogod), colour=discord.Colour(0xFFFFFF))
                                    await i.add_roles(togiverole)
                                    await i.remove_roles(role)
                                    #hasadded=True
                                    await channel.send(removedliteral)
                                    return
                            elif rolenumber==0:
                                await i.remove_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="God"))
                            else:
                                await i.remove_roles(discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="God"))
                                await i.remove_roles(role)
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        await channel.send(errorliteral)
```

The code is a bit messup, but is been a while that i dont code in python, so here a little explaination (ps, this is a little funny thing that i want to add to my server, like, everyone is a god, if they do something funny i add gods, if not i remove gods, so if they dont have enough gods (<0) i will remove the real God role, who gives permissions):
i get the channel where i should send the messages
i get the number of gods to remove
i set rolenumber to 0, then
i get the guild, if the name is in the peoples that can do this, for every member i'll search for persona, who is the member to remove gods from
then, if the role is a int that means i found the role i want to modify, if the number of his gods is more than 1, i will so remove gods like, if is 27 and i remove 20 it will possibily create a new role or give a already created one, if is 0 it will remove the number role, and if is <0 then i want to remove the "God" role, who gives permissions.

ANSWER:
Move the role who should have more permissions higher than the role who should be "dominated" in the roles list!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions` means the bot failed to do something because of the *bot's* permissions. This is separate from the bot owner, which is another user with independent permissions.

You need to give the bot permission to do whatever action you are performing. This is done in your server/guild config.

If you are writing commands that only a bot owner can do, there is a decorator called `is_owner` in Discord.py

Comment: Hello! thanks for the speed answer and sorry for my late reply, can you link me the docs for is_owner? Thanks!

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.is_owner

Comment: thanks, but how can this help me? i already make that check (by myself), the bot then should remove that role, that only owner can normally remove, i didn't find anything searching

Comment: I'm not following what you're trying to do then. what role are you trying to remove? Can you provide code?

Comment: oh sure sorry, i will modify the question

Comment: Modified, sorry, is a bit long

Comment: If you are just trying to remove roles, make sure your bot has permission to do that

Comment: Sure he has, i gave him all permissions i can, but even the role he tries to remove has all the permission, i think this is the problem

Comment: The docs confirm your suspicion: "You must have the manage_roles permission to use this, and the removed Roles must appear lower in the list of roles than the highest role of the member." https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.remove_roles

Comment: Thanks! im not that good with discord, so the solution was just move the permission in the permission list :)